# Sharing files over network - accessing files on a Mac from a Win7 machine

Tags: windows-7, mac-osx, file-sharing

This is one of those questions that has a million web sites explaining how simple it is, but for some reason I'm living in some edge case that is being difficult.

First the details:

Mac is running OSX 10.7.5, File Sharing is enabled, both AFP and SMB sharing are enabled, and both of the users that appear under SMB ("Administrator" and "Guest") are enabled for SMB sharing.

Both the Mac and the Windows machines are on a LAN where most user accounts come from a Network Account Server (OD).

From Windows, I try to connect to the shared drive on the Mac, and it asks me for a username/password, but nothing works.  I've tried Admin/password, Administrator/password, Guest/password, and various combinations of my actual Windows login (crokkerb/password) which the OD server recognizes but the Mac apparently doesn't.

I am guessing that (1) even though I type in the correct username/password for the two accounts the Mac does know about ("Administrator" and "Guest"), somehow I can't gain access using those accounts, and (2) the Mac isn't populating the list of users (for SMB access) from the OD server.

Suggestions on what else I can try here?

p.s. Bonus points for a solution that lets me connect to this shared drive without having to type in any username/password.

Comment: SuperUser?  Or why is this about professional IT?

Comment: The ServerFault page says this is a "question and answer site for professional system and network administrators" so I assumed it was a good place to ask a network administration question ... was it not?

Comment: Well... that's what I'm asking... *is* this a professional network administration question, or a *trying-to-share-files-across-my-home-LAN* question?  IF it's the former, more details on how the Mac interacts with the network accounts server would probably help.  If it's the latter, you'll probably find better help on SuperUser.  (Or maybe even AskDifferent.)

Comment: I am currently sitting in an office, being paid to do computery stuff, and while most of the time that means writing software, today's job is to figure out this file sharing.  So ... does that count as professional?  In the hopes that I do meet the criteria, I will proceed with answering your question, although I'm not sure I can provide much insight.  The OD server is maintained at the corporate office in another state, all I can do is enable it in the "Users & Groups" preferences tab on the Mac.

Comment: Yes, that's close enough for our purposes. And it sounds like the Mac isn't recognizing the Open Directory server, or allowing access for OD accounts.  Probably the first thing I'd do to nail down the source of the problem is to create a local account on the Mac, give it permissions to the shared drive, and try to use to access that drive from a Windows machine with that local account. If that works, you know the problem is with something to do with the OpenDirectory setup - either the server itself, the way the Mac is setup to auth against it, or the permissions OD accounts have on the Mac.

Comment: I created a local account on the Mac, added it as a Read-Only user on the folder I'm sharing, and enabled the new user for SMB sharing.  I then switched over to the Windows box, and in Windows Explorer I entered double-back-slash followed by the IP of the Mac.  It asked me to enter my Network Password, defaulted to my Windows user, instead I clicked on "Use another account" and enter the username & password of the newly-created Mac user.  It says "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password" (though it also says "Domain: BETTY-PC" which might be a problem?

Comment: If you SSH to this mac can you login the credentials you expect?  Can you login locally to the OSX box with the credentials you are trying?

Comment: Yes to both - I can SSH from a second Mac to the mac containing the folder-to-be-shared, using the credentials of the created-for-this-purpose user, and I can log in directly/locally using the same credentials.